# Как отсортировать массив объектов?

Tags: сортировка, объекты, javascript

Есть массив вида

```
var arr = [
    {
        fiels: {
            name: "a",
            alt: "a2"
        },
        count: 4
    },
    {
        fiels: {
            name: "b",
            alt: "3"
        },
        count: 3
    },
];
```

Нужно отсортировать массив в двух вариантах:

1. По значению "fields.name".
2. По count.

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: На [Википедии](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F) есть реализация сортировки на js. Вместо элемента массива обращайтесь к соответствующей переменной объекта. При сортировке по имени сравнивайте первый символ имени. Если в одном из слов отсутствует символ, при совпадении предыдущих букв, считайте этот элемент меньшим. У символов нумерация последовательная, так что 'a'<'b'. Удач

Answer (score 0):

Вот что получилось

```
var json = vehicle.sort(function(one, two) {
    if (one.name < two.name) return -1;
    if (one.name > two.name) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

По значению "fields.name":

```
arr.sort(function (a, b){ return a.fiels.name > b.fiels.name });
```

По count:

```
arr.sort(function (a, b){return a.count - b.count});
```